# Creating random number and appending to list

Tags: list, append

populate each hand with two cards. Take a card from the deck
and put it in the player_hand list. Then, take a card from the deck and
put it in the dealer_hand list. Do that one more time in that order so that the dealer and player have each two cards. Make sure the dealer's first card is face down. I keep receiving this error from my 2 tests.

My code:

```
 while len(dealer_hand) != 2 and len(player_hand) != 2:
        player_card = random.choice(deck)
        player_hand.append(player_card)
        deck.remove(player_card)
        if len(player_hand) == 2:
            player_hand[0].face_up()
            player_hand[1].face_up()
        dealer_card = random.choice(deck)
        dealer_hand.append(dealer_card)
        deck.remove(dealer_card)
        if len(dealer_hand) == 2:
            dealer_hand[0].face_down()
            dealer_hand[1].face_up()

    return player_hand and dealer_hand


False != True

Expected :True
Actual   :False

def test_deal_cards():
        deck = []
        for suit in cards.SUITS:
            for rank in cards.RANKS:
                deck.append(cards.Card(suit, rank))
        dealer_hand = []
        player_hand = []
    
        blackjack.deal_cards(deck, dealer_hand, player_hand)
    
        assert len(dealer_hand) == 2
        assert len(player_hand) == 2
>       assert dealer_hand[0].is_face_up() is True
E       assert False is True
E        +  where False = <bound method Card.is_face_up of [10 of Hearts]>()
E        +    where <bound method Card.is_face_up of [10 of Hearts]> = [10 of Hearts].is_face_up

test_deal_cards.py:19: AssertionError





(test_deal_cards_alternates_between_player_and_dealer)
[7 of Hearts] != [6 of Spades]

Expected :[6 of Spades]
Actual   :[7 of Hearts]

def test_deal_cards_alternates_between_player_and_dealer():
        card1 = cards.Card(cards.SPADES, cards.SIX)
        card2 = cards.Card(cards.HEARTS, cards.SEVEN)
        card3 = cards.Card(cards.CLUBS, cards.EIGHT)
        card4 = cards.Card(cards.DIAMONDS, cards.NINE)
    
        deck = [card4, card3, card2, card1]
    
        dealer_hand = []
        player_hand = []
        blackjack.deal_cards(deck, dealer_hand, player_hand)
    
        assert len(dealer_hand) == 2
        assert len(player_hand) == 2
>       assert player_hand[0] is card1, 'Player 1st card should be Six of Spades'
E       AssertionError: Player 1st card should be Six of Spades
E       assert [7 of Hearts] is [6 of Spades]

test_deal_cards.py:39: AssertionError
```

Comment: I keep getting a error from my test saying, "Expected: 2, Actual: 0"

Answer (score 0):

I think the error lies within the first line:

```
while len(dealer_hand) and len(player_hand) != 2:
```

If you want to check if the dealer also has 2 cards, you need to fix that line to:

```
while len(dealer_hand) != 2 and len(player_hand) != 2:
```